# About Taylor series

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation

Suppose $f(0) = 0, f'(0) = 2,  f''(0) = −1$  and $|f''' (x)| ≤ 0.024$ for $0 ≤ x ≤ 2$.  Estimate $f(1)$ to $4$ significant figures by using a Taylor polynomial. Compute a good bound for the absolute error.
What's the point of mentioning that f'''(x)<0.024??

Comment: Hey man, this will probably be deleted if you don't include what you've tried. We're not going to just do your homework. Cheers!

Comment: The question, as posed, is "What's the point of mentioning that $\lvert f'''(x) \rvert\leq 0.024$?" If one does not remember (or guess) that one can find in the textbook an explicit formula for precisely this kind of problem using precisely that kind of information about $f'''$, one is completely stuck. So I'd say the question as posed is about as much "work" as we can reasonably demand OP to show. It also requires only a very brief answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac12f''(0)x^2+\frac16f'''(\xi)x^3$$

is valid for $x\in [0,2]$ for some $0<\xi<2$

Comment: Ok, but what is the good bound for the absolute error??

Comment: Mohammad Use the bound on the third derivative.  -Mark

Answer (score 1):

The point of that information is that you should look at the Lagrange form of the remainder.